# RegEx - How to find all occurrences, including newlines, between two points?

Tags: regex

Assume I have

```
    changed: true
    newTranslated: ''
    importedTokens: true
```

and (notice there is no ' ' here)

```
    changed: true
    newTranslated: 
    Some cool text here
    Here is some more next
    importedTokens: true
```

and

```
    changed: true
    newTranslated: '|cFFASD2Hello there!'
    importedTokens: true
```

I want to search everything, including newlines between changed: true and importedTokens (this includes changed: true, but not importedTokens). I also do not want to match **newTranslated: ''**

With this RegEx, I match changed: true and any newTranslated, except (NewTranslated: '').

```
changed: true\n.*^((?!'').)*$
```

but only the first line of newTranslated it fetches, I want it to keep going until it finds "importedTokens", but does not include it in the match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a pattern with a capture group and a negative lookahead:

```
\bchanged:\s*true((?:\n(?!\s*\b(?:newTranslated:\s*''|importTokens:|changed:)).*)*)(?=\n\s*\bimportedTokens:)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bchanged:\s*true` Match the word `changed` and then `:` optional spaces and true
- `(` Capture **group 1** (that has the data you are interested in)

  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part
  - `\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!\s*\b(?:newTranslated:\s*''|importTokens:|changed:)).*)*` Match the whole line if is does not contain any of the alternatives
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?=\n\s*\bimportedTokens:)` Positive lookahead, assert a newline and `importedTokens:`